# How to run .py scripts from Java code?

Tags: java, python

I am a beginner in Python and I need to call `.py` script from Java code. I have installed `jython` but the tutorials I am getting online has material where they are importing Java packages in Python code. But my query is the other way round.

I just need a simple code in Java which is able to run Python scripts`(.py)`.

Any leads will be highly appreciated.

Comment: just search on google "call .py script from java code" and get the answer `Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python yourapp.py");`

Answer (score 1):

Use jython library or run in CMD:

```
String command = "python script.py";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```